# Solution for an exponential expression without using logarithms, with two defined variables

Tags: exponentiation

> If $60^a=3$ and $60^b=5$, what is the result of $12^{\frac{1-a-b}{-2-2b}}$?

This has to be done without logarithms. The past four hours were helpless to me. Any hint, solution is welcome, I just want to learn it, or it will continue to bug my head

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand this **so 12 = 5/60 = 60^(1-b),** could you help me?

Comment: @WanderleyTiowann It should be mentioned that this post was over two years old.  Had I not noticed you ask this question from the review queues, it would have likely gone unanswered.  As it so happens, there was a typo.  It should have been $12=\frac{60}{5}$, which by the condition that $60^b = 5$ becomes $\frac{60}{5} = \frac{60}{60^b} = 60^{1-b}$.  I have improved the formatting of the answer so it is hopefully easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's not $12^\frac{1-a-b}{2-2b}$? Because that works out nicely, but the posted version doesn't. I'll show the working for this version.

$60^b = 5$, so $12 = \frac{60}{5} = 60^{1-b}$.

So $12^{\frac{1-a-b}{2-2b}} = (60^{1-b})^{\frac{1-a-b}{2-2b}} = 60^{\frac{(1-a-b)(1-b)}{2-2b}} = 60^{\frac{1-a-b}{2}} = (\frac{60}{60^a60^b})^{1/2} = (\frac{60}{3\cdot 5})^{1/2} = 4^{1/2} = 2$